# Finding ring isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory, group-isomorphism

Find isomorphism from $F_5[x]/(x^2+x+2) \rightarrow F_5[x]/(x^2+4x+2) $
I realise both polynomials are irreducible therefore form fields, not sure how to form a isomorphism from one to the other, help please

Comment: It might be helpful to remember that there is (up to isomorphism) exactly _one_ quadratic extension of $\mathbb{F}_5$ to which therefore both of the fields in your question must be isomorphic.